# PHP cookie not deleting

Tags: php, cookies

I have read through various threads but none of the solutions seem to work.

I have two PHP pages:

**cookieson.php**

```
<?php session_start();
$future = time()+60*60*24*30*12;
setcookie('CookiesAgreed', 'yes', $future, '/');
?>
```

**cookiesoff.php**

```
<?php session_start();
$past = time()-9999999999999999;
setcookie('CookiesAgreed', null, $past, '/');
?>
```

cookieson.php correctly sets the cookie "CookiesAgreed" with an expiration approximately a year away.

cookiesoff.php should clear the "CookiesAgreed" cookie altogether, but doesn't seem to do anything - the value doesn't change (according to Firefox's Cookies list), the expiration doesn't change, and the cookie doesn't delete. Occasionally a brand new cookie is created (again, according to Firefox) with the same name, value and expiration date.

What am I doing wrong?!

(You can see at http://www.rugbyfiles.com/cookieson.php and http://www.rugbyfiles.com/cookiesoff.php)

Comment: With my firefox 18 i cant reproduce it. Firebug lists no cookies except the session identifier.

Comment: just saying the cookie law is being canceled,  thats the last thing I've heard :)

Comment: D'oh. Me being stupid. I assumed Firefox's Cookie list window would dynamically update with deleted cookies (like it does with added cookies which appear automatically).

Turns out you have to OK your way out of the window, then open it again, to see the removed cookies.

Apologies.

Answer (score 7):

This goes out of stack and overflows:

```
$past = time()-9999999999999999;
```

Instead, do this way:

```
$past = time()-60*60*24*30*12;
```

The time variable can hold only values from `0` to `4294967296`. When you give such a long negative value, it goes out of stack.

Comment: Ha ha... Was intentional. :) But those are the only words I can use. :)

Comment: Stuart Pinfold came to the right website to ask for help, hehe :D

Comment: `$past = time() - 31104000;// 60*60*24*30*12` to avoid run-time calculation.

Comment: D'oh. Me being stupid. I assumed Firefox's Cookie list window would dynamically update with deleted cookies (like it does with added cookies which appear automatically).

Turns out you have to OK your way out of the window, then open it again, to see the removed cookies.

Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

```
setcookie("CookiesAgreed","",time()-24*60*60,"/");
```

Comment: Please add some details about your answer.